# Printing text file contents into columns

Tags: php, text

I have this text file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_1cAszh75fYSjNPZFRPb0trOFE/view?usp=sharing

I can print it using the following code:

```
$file = fopen("gl20160630.txt","r");
while(! feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br />";
  }
fclose($file);
```

But it looks like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/4uM6iY7]

I want the contents of this text file to be separated into four columns -Line,  Description, Legacy GL Code and Closing Balance. If any one of these columns is empty it should remain empty. I just want to print those lines that start with ====>

Could you please help me find a way to print the text file like the way I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple, since your file has a strict number of character for each column.

All you need to do is a [substr](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr.php) on each line starting by '====>{line}', then you can read each column by there position in the file.

Here is an example using your file :

```
$file = fopen("gl20160630.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
{
    $fullLine =  fgets($file);

    $line = substr($fullLine, 5, 4);

    if (is_numeric($line)) {
        $liability = trim(substr($fullLine, 10, 30));

        $legacy = trim(substr($fullLine, 40, 39));

        $balance = trim(substr($fullLine, 79, 15));

        if ($liability != null && $legacy != null && $balance != null)
            echo $line." ".$liability." ".$legacy." ".$balance."\n";
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

You can see that all I do is:

- check if the character in the column 'Line' are numbers
- then I get all the other element
- I 'clean' them by getting rid of unwanted characters (spaces, ...) with [trim](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.trim.php)
- After that, I check that all elements are filed
- And I finally display them

I hope that this will help you, have a nice day ;)

Comment: I am afraid, the above code doesn't work like the way I wanted. I wanted 4 columns in a line. But this is how it looks now:  http://i.imgur.com/3q3XnFg.png

Comment: I can't do all the work for you, you already have each data in a variable, you can change the look very easily.

For example by changing this:

echo $line." ".$liability." ".$legacy." ".$balance."\n";

into this:

echo $line." ".$liability." ".$legacy." ".$balance."<br />";

you will display 4 columns.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it worked. Thanks for your help.